# python - dumping a nested dict with correct indentation to yaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm painfully close to automating the dump of a yml file that's created from a data frame for an automation task.

I have a function that is structured like the following:

```
def get_all_values(nested_dictionary):
    for key,value in nested_dictionary.items():
        model = {
           "models": [
                {
            "name": key,
              "columns": None
                }
            ]
        }            
        yield(model)
        for key,value in value.items():
                table = [
                    {
                       "name": key,
                            "tests": [            
                                "not_null",
                                "unique"            
                            ]
                       }
                ]
                yield(table)
    nested_dictionary = d1
    get_all_values(nested_dictionary)
    data = get_all_values(nested_dictionary)
    with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
        with redirect_stdout(outfile):
            for i in data:
                ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(i,outfile, indent=5, block_seq_indent=2)
```

The dict it references is yielded as a generator. The dicts structure is:

```
    {'models': [{'name': 'budgets_sales', 'columns': None}]}
[{'name': 'budget_amt', 'tests': ['not_null', 'unique']}]
[{'name': 'budget_group', 'tests': ['not_null', 'unique']}]
[{'name': 'budget_name', 'tests': ['not_null', 'unique']}]
[{'name': 'budget_pk', 'tests': ['not_null', 'unique']}]
```

This works "well'...but the output is as follows:

```
models:
  -  name: budgets_sales
     columns:
  -  name: budget_amt
     tests:
       -  not_null
       -  unique
  -  name: budget_group
     tests:
       -  not_null
       -  unique
  -  name: budget_name
     tests:
       -  not_null
       -  unique
```

I require all values to keys in the dict to have an additional indentation. I cannot figure out how to make the values indented against the keys.

It would look like this if correct:

```
- name: budgets_sales
  columns:
      -  name: budget_amt
         tests:
            -  not_null
            -  unique
      -  name: budget_group
         tests:
            -  not_null
            -  unique
      -  name: budget_name
         tests:
            -  not_null
            -  unique
      -  name: budget_pk
         tests:
            -  not_null
            -  unique
      -  name: entry_type_code
         tests:
            -  not_null
            -  unique
      -  name: institution_fk
         tests:
            -  not_null
            -  unique
```

Could anyone provide an approach?

---

Thanks to Anthon, this is what I ended up using:

```
def get_all_values(nested_dictionary):
    res = [{"version":2},{"models":None}]
    for key,value in nested_dictionary.items():
        seq = []
        res.append([{"name": key, "columns": seq}])
        # for key1, value1 in value.items():  # not using value1
        for key1 in value.keys():
            elem = {"name": key1, "tests": ["not_null", "unique"]}
            seq.append(elem)
    return res

nested_dictionary = d1

get_all_values(nested_dictionary)

data = get_all_values(nested_dictionary)

    
with open('data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    
    with redirect_stdout(outfile):
        
        for i in data:  
            
            yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
            yaml.indent(mapping=5, sequence=5, offset=4)            
            yml.dump(i,outfile)
```

Comment: Perhaps use a YAML formatter as a final step, once you have generated the valid .yml file?

Comment: Hi zr0gravity7. Let me give this a try. Were you thinking in a text editor or another function within python?

Comment: @LewisBaker I tried to update your code and your data (which both contained invalid YAML). I hope that represent what you want, if not edit the post, paste in your code, select it and press Ctrl+K to indent the whole thing so it looks like code/data in the post.

Comment: You cannot have an offset of 4 in 5 positions, there has to be a space after the element indicator (`-`), IIRC the offset is reduced automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your required output the value associated with key `columns` is a sequence.
You only get that if your Python data structure is a list, so make sure you
append your individual `table` entries to some variable.

I am guessing `d1` based on your "incorrect" output:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

d1 = dict(budgets_sales=dict(budget_amt=None, budget_group=None, budget_name=None, budget_pk=None))

def get_all_values(nested_dictionary):
    res = []
    for key,value in nested_dictionary.items():
        seq = []
        res.append({"name": key, "columns": seq})
        # for key1, value1 in value.items():  # not using value1
        for key1 in value.keys():
            elem = {"name": key, "tests": ["not_null", "unique"]}
            seq.append(elem)
    return res
    
data = get_all_values(d1)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=5, sequence=5, offset=3)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
   - name: budgets_sales
     columns:
        - name: budgets_sales
          tests:
             - not_null
             - unique
        - name: budgets_sales
          tests:
             - not_null
             - unique
        - name: budgets_sales
          tests:
             - not_null
             - unique
        - name: budgets_sales
          tests:
             - not_null
             - unique
```

There are a few things you should take into account (apart from better formatting your code and data here on SO):

- the `round_trip_dump` function has been deprecated, don't use it in new code
- the recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml`, since at least Sep 2007
- don't write YAML files in multiple stages, create one complete data structure and dump it. If you want multiple YAML documents in one file, make a list of data structures and use the `.dump_all()` method.

If all else fails and you have valid handcrafted YAML that you want to generate as output, load that YAML (with `YAML(typ='safe').load()` and inspect the data structure in Python that you get.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply Anthon (apologies for the badly formatted code). I'm going to try and refactor my code to your recommendations and will reply again after

Comment: I'm still struggling to produce the correct output. I used your snippets but must be missing something as this does not iterate through the key, values pairs in the dict.

Could you provide some detail on the relationship between the data dict and tables and the dump perhaps? I'm unclear on how tables = [] ends up in the dump. Thanks again

Comment: Is the "correct" output in your post formatted as you want it?

Comment: It is indeed. Do you have another approach in mind?

I have tried some other iterations without success. I will update if I get any closer.

Comment: Anthon, that's it! That works perfectly. I made some small changes as in your example it iterates through the keys.

I need to now break what you have done down so I better understand it. 

Thank you for taking the time to help out with this.

Comment: I'm going to edit my question with that I ended up using, in case it's useful for future context

Comment: Also, the .yml extension is duly noted. This is designed to work with a utility that only utilises .yml extensions unfortunately